# R: Union Spatial Polygons won't remove separation line completely

Tags: r, gis, geospatial, r-sp, rgdal

**Story and data:**
I'm doing an internship at a farm in Estonia and want to print out a site plan (sketch) of their fields. However, the shapefile of the fields I get from the Estonian Ministery for Agriculture (https://kls.pria.ee/kaart -> drop-down menu: Põllumassiivid -> Taotlejanimi = "Pahkla Camphilli Küla Farmi OÜ" -> in the search results: Lae andmed alla -> ESRI SHP | I'm sorry, but I don't know how to provide the data elsehow, since the download links there aren't stable) has the fields divided as they were in a certain year:

[image: Raw data from Estonian Ministry of Agriculture]

But the fragmentation is almost every year slightly different, so I want to have a minimal fragmentation. Therefore I want to merge some of the polygons.

**What I do:**

```
library(rgdal)
library(rgeos)

# Read in data:
fields <- readOGR("PCK_fields.shp")

# Add ID-column for merging:
fields$põllunumbrid <- character(length(fields$xy_id))
fields$põllunumbrid[grepl("55155929528", as.character(fields$xy_id)) | grepl("55155926080", as.character(fields$xy_id))] <- "1"
fields$põllunumbrid[grepl("55155918524", as.character(fields$xy_id)) | grepl("55155908713", as.character(fields$xy_id)) |
                      grepl("55155916421", as.character(fields$xy_id))] <- "2"
fields$põllunumbrid[grepl("55055979669", as.character(fields$xy_id))] <- "3"
fields$põllunumbrid[grepl("55155904072", as.character(fields$xy_id))] <- "4"
fields$põllunumbrid[grepl("55055978792", as.character(fields$xy_id)) | grepl("55055958459", as.character(fields$xy_id))] <- "5"
fields$põllunumbrid[grepl("55055959045", as.character(fields$xy_id))] <- "6A"
fields$põllunumbrid[grepl("55056021718", as.character(fields$xy_id))] <- "6B"
fields$põllunumbrid[grepl("55056047115", as.character(fields$xy_id))] <- "7A"
fields$põllunumbrid[grepl("55056047987", as.character(fields$xy_id))] <- "7B"
fields$põllunumbrid[grepl("55055982185", as.character(fields$xy_id))] <- "8A"
fields$põllunumbrid[grepl("55055970417", as.character(fields$xy_id))] <- "8B"
fields$põllunumbrid[grepl("55155910853", as.character(fields$xy_id))] <- "9"
fields$põllunumbrid[grepl("55055956707", as.character(fields$xy_id))] <- "10"
fields$põllunumbrid[grepl("55055924834", as.character(fields$xy_id))] <- "11"
fields$põllunumbrid[grepl("54955995000", as.character(fields$xy_id))] <- "12"
fields$põllunumbrid[grepl("55055997994", as.character(fields$xy_id))] <- "Aed"

# Perform Union
fields1 <- gUnaryUnion(fields, id = fields$põllunumbrid)
# or
#library(maptools)
#fields1 <- unionSpatialPolygons(fields, fields$põllunumbrid)
```

**What I get:**
[image: After performing Union]
(`maptools::unionSpatialPolygons()` and QGIS' dissolve give exactly the same results)

Some dividing lines seem to be removed unproperly. Interestingly this depends on the coordinate system/ projection. If I first reproject the polygons to WGS84 via

```
fields <- spTransform(fields, CRS("+init=epsg:4326"))
```

Then the result contains a different line in the problematic area that almost separates two of the former polygons:
[image: After performing Union different coordinate system]

**What I want:**
But I want these polygon borders to vanish completely!

**What I tried aswell:**
Because the problems arise only there where I merge 3 polygons I tried to first merging 2 of them an then the third one in aswell. However, this leaves me with the separating line between the two and the third one completely untouched.

If I try (so far only with QGIS) to turn the polygons into lines, split them at their vertices, and take those edges out that divide the polygons then there is an edge that needs further shortening. Doing that aswell leaves me with the problem that `lines to polygons` won't produce any output. Going then back to R again using [the trick from Kamran Safi](http://grokbase.com/t/r/r-sig-geo/0933fcdcbf/spatiallines-to-spatialpolygons-convertion) to force a conversion back to polygons gives me a lot of polygons with an area of 0, i.e. the plot looks right, but the polygons plotted then are only lines.

**Qustion:**
Does someone know a workaround that properly removes all of the unneeded polygon borders?

Comment: I guess it would raise my chances for an answer tremendously, if it wouldn't be that hard to get the data. So if anyone knows a good method to provide you the small shapefile (52 KB unzipped) I would be happy to hear it.

Comment: Not quite an answer, but it worked for me and may help others in my situation aswell: After converting the polygons to lines, splitting the lines up at their vertices (QGIS: Processing -> Tools -> Explode) and deleting the separation lines I could use the QGIS: Processing -> Tools -> Polygonize tool to recreate all but one polygon. This one I drew anew with help of snapping. It's not 100% the original one, so I can't use the data for official purposes any more, but it will do for me.

Comment: I guess with all that QGIS stuff that came into it to describe what I did in my despair the question would be placed better in the GIS Stack-Exchange Community now.

Comment: Depending of the precision your need, you may want to make a small buffer around your shapes (like 1 meter or so, smaller is the better).  It may help with your specific problem but also may cause other problems...

Comment: @Bastien this is much better than my solution. I used a buffer of 1 mm which fulfills my needs of accuracy by far.